# couchbase is installed but still getting import error (Pyinstaller)

Tags: python, python-2.7, couchbase, pyinstaller

I am trying to build python source code using `pyinstaller`. Once Building is successful I am running the binary file. Once I run the binary file I am getting the following `ImportError`:

```
PyUtils.CouchbaseClient", line 13, in <module>
ImportError: No module named couchbase
```

But `couchbase` is already installed and I am able to run the original Python source code without any import errors. After converting into the binary I am getting ImportError.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any warning or errors during the build process? How is the module imported and where does it reside?

Comment: Build was successful with out any Errors or warnings. This is the command which i used to build the code.  Command: pyinstaller -p path1:path2:path3  Test/Main.py      Couch Base i installed with easy_install: sudo easy_install couchbase

Comment: How is the module imported in the code? Perhaps it's a dynamic import, or done in an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: It is a dynamic import and also i created empty __init__.py file

Answer (score 3):

Since your program dynamically imports *couchbase*, *pyinstaller* can't detect that it is required, as specified in the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#analysis-finding-the-files-your-program-needs):

> Some *Python* scripts import modules in ways that *PyInstaller* cannot detect: for example, by using the `__import__()` function with variable data, or manipulating the `sys.path` value at run time.

[Another section of the documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#listing-hidden-imports) extends on this issue and suggests some workarounds for dealing with this scenario:

> If Analysis thinks it has found all the imports, but the app fails with an import error, the problem is a hidden import; that is, an import that is not visible to the analysis phase.
>
> Hidden imports can occur when the code is using `__import__` or perhaps `exec` or `eval`. You get warnings of these (see [Build-time Messages](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#build-time-messages)).
>
> Hidden imports can also occur when an extension module uses the *Python/C API* to do an import. When this occurs, Analysis can detect nothing. There will be no warnings, only a crash at run-time.
>
> To find these hidden imports, set the `-v` flag ([Getting Python's Verbose Imports](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#getting-python-s-verbose-imports) above).
>
> Once you know what they are, you add the needed modules to the bundle using the `--hidden-import=` command option, by editing the spec file, or with a hook file (see [Using Hook Files](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#using-hook-files) below).

Therefore, you need to explicitly ask *pyinstaller* to include the required module during the build process. It seems that the easiest way to do so is with the [`--hidden-import`](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#options-for-finding-imported-modules-and-libraries) argument:

> `--hidden-import=modulename`
> Name an imported *Python* module that is not visible in your code. The module will be included as if it was named in an `import` statement. This option can be given more than once.

Thus, please add the following argument when building the application:

`--hidden-import=couchbase`

---

However, once *PyInstaller* detects that `couchbase` is required, running the resulting executable fails with an `ImportError`:

```
ImportError: No module named _libcouchbase
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919917/3903832) describes what should be done in order to resolve it.

Comment: I again tried with the --hidden-import=couchbase,but still i am getting the same error: Here is the command which i used:                                      pyinstaller -p Automator/AutomationFramework/:PyUtils/:Telco/  --hidden-import=couchbase Forge/telcoPipeline/pyscripts/main.py

Comment: In addition to the `--hidden-import` argument, try building with the argument `--log-level=debug` and check whether anything is written about importing *couchbase*. Also, when executing the application, add the [`-v` flag for verbose import messages](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#getting-python-s-verbose-imports).

Comment: 1712 DEBUG: Analyzing libcouchbase
1713 ERROR: Hidden import 'libcouchbase' not found
1713 INFO: Analyzing hidden import '_libcouchbase'
1713 DEBUG: Analyzing _libcouchbase
1714 ERROR: Hidden import '_libcouchbase' not found

Comment: This is actually a different error, which deserves its own question. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30919917/3903832), which I've also linked to in my answer, addresses it.

Comment: Tried with the answer. But still i am getting the same error.        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/bhanu/Test/build/main/out00-PYZ.pyz/couchbase.exceptions", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _libcouchbase

Comment: What debug log messages do you get?